# In Python, how to invoke subroutine inside [if __name__ == '__main__'] of another py file?

Tags: python, program-entry-point, python-module

Assuming that I am in a python console and want to launch another python program in the same process. The python program looks like this:

```
import sys

if __name__ == '__main__':
      args = sys.argv
      for key in args:
          print(key)
```

and I'm not allowed to modify it.

What is the proper way of doing this? Can I call it's 'main function' with a different list of arguments like C++ or Java?

I'm not against method are are considered hacking. Python is a highly extendable interpreted language and I'll do whatever necessary to bypass this restriction

Comment: To clarify, are you not allowed to touch the python file at all? Sounds like some CTF question to me.

Comment: Run it as a script, as it is intended to be run.

Comment: @pkqxdd, no I can't, specifically, the original untouchable file is mavproxy.py. this is definitely not  a CTF question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't "call its main function", because it doesn't have one.

In fact, the usual way to handle this is to move all those code into a function, then make the `__main__` guard code just call that:

```
def main(args):
    for key in args:
        print(key)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main(sys.argv)
```

Then you *can* call its main function, passing it any args you want.

But if you can't fix the file, that won't work.

---

So, what *can* you do? It all depends on how exactly you need to follow the usual `python another.py` semantics.

---

The quick&dirty way is to do what [blhsing's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51550500/908494) suggests: read the file, and [`exec`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#exec) it with the [globals](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#globals) from your own script:

```
with open('another.py') as f:
    exec(f.read(), globals())
```

Notice that this is going to leave `sys.argv` untouched. You can, of course, manually set it to something else first:

```
_argv = sys.argv
sys.argv = ['args', 'i', 'want', 'it', 'to', 'see']
try:
    with open('another.py') as f:
        exec(f.read(), globals())
finally:
    sys.argv = _argv
```

---

If you're doing this from another module, rather than from your top-level script, that won't work, but with a slight modification, it will:

```
with open('another.py') as f:
    exec(f.read(), sys.modules['__main__'].__dict__)
```

---

But you may be better off creating a clean global namespace. The script may not expect to have your globals sitting around—and it may change things you don't want it to change. This is just as easy:

```
with open('another.py') as f:
    exec(f.read(), {})
```

(Note that this will still automatically inherit the current [`builtins`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/builtins.html#module-builtins), which you usually want. If you *don't* want that for some reason, see the `exec` docs.)

---

If you want to guarantee that you're executing it exactly the same way as running a script normally, use the [`runpy`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/runpy.html) module.

When you run `python -m another`, what it ultimately does is:

```
runpy.run_module(sys.argv[0], run_name="__main__", alter_sys=True)
```

So, you can do the same thing manually:

```
runpy.run_module('another', run_name='__main__')
```

Whether you want to add `alter_sys=True` depends on what you're after. Without it, if the script tries to access `sys.argv` (as your script does) or `sys.modules['__main__']`, it will see your values, instead of its own.

---

If you want to emulate `python another.py`, you'd want to use [`importlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/runpy.html) to create a full `__spec__` and related objects, then calls `runpy.run_path`.

Comment: thanks a lot! very comprehensive and exactly what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 2):

You can read the file and use `exec` to execute the code with the current globals so that `__name__ == '__main__'` would be true.

```
exec(open('file.py').read(), globals())
```